# Подогнать размер картинки, находящейся удаленно

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте! У меня есть форма, а в ней кнопка:

```
<input type="image" src="<?=$a_img_s?>">
```

Каждый раз я загружаю в нее разные изображения по `url`. Мне нужно, чтобы это изображение всегда пропорционально влезало в `width:200`, `height:300`. 
То есть оно может быть меньше, но не может превышать эти значения. Изображение не должно искажаться, то есть нельзя просто определить значения `width` и `height`.

Я пробовал сделать так:

```
<input type="image" src="<?=$a_img_s?>"><?if(imagesy($a_img_s)>300){return "height=300;";}?>>
```

Однако это не сработало, и совсем не пропорционально. У изображений может быть больше как и `height`, так и `width.` Помогите чем-то. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую сделать сие через JS. Аргументы:

1. На вывод страницы с сотней таких картинок уйдет куча времени, ибо для этого нужен как минимум запрос на сервер картинки
2. Без кэширования это неправильно идейно, хотя это расширение 1 пункта
3. В JS есть img.onload, который решит эту задачу, имхо, лучше.

Вот мой вариант (отлаженный, рабочий)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function correctImageSize(img) {
  var was = {
    w: img.offsetWidth,
    h: img.offsetHeight
    }
  var max = {
    w: 300,
    h: 200
    }
  if (!was.w || !was.h) return false; // anti DBZ
  var rK = {
    w: max.w/was.w,
    h: max.h/was.h
    }
  var resizeK = (rK.w > rK.h) ? rK.h : rK.w; 
  img.width = Math.floor(resizeK * was.w);
  img.height = Math.floor(resizeK * was.h);
  return true;
  }
</script>
<div style="width: 300px;height: 200px;border: #0f0 1px dashed;text-align: center;">
<img src="http://www.google.ru/images/nav_logo89.png" onload="correctImageSize(this);" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
function insertScales($imgx,$imgy,$maxx=200,$maxy=300){
if($imgy<=0 || $maxy<=0 || $imgx<=0 || $maxx<=0){
    return;
}
$ratio = $imgx/$imgy;

if($ratio>($maxx/$maxy)){
  if($imgx>$maxx){
    $imgx = $maxx;
    $imgy = $imgx/$ratio;
  }
}else{
  if($imgy>$maxy){
    $imgy = $maxy;
    $imgx = $imgy*$ratio;
  }
}
return 'width="'.$imgx.'px" height="'.$imgy.'px"';
}
?>
<input type="image" src="<?=$a_img_s?>" <?=insertScales(imagesx(imagecreatefromjpg($a_img_s)),imagesy(imagecreatefromjpg($a_img_s)))?> />
```

Comment: При вызове функции ошибки( 

Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in Z:\home\elo\www\form.php on line 74

Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in Z:\home\elo\www\form.php on line 74
"/>

строка 74, это тот самый input

Comment: imagesy(imagecreatefromjpg($a_img_s)) - так попробуйте. Странно, что у вас работало

Comment: а imagecreatefromjpg разве по URL работает? о_О

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpg()

у меня что-то не установлено?

Comment: Для определения поддерживается ли GD выполнить следующий скрипт!

    <?php
    
    if(function_exists('imagetypes'))
      echo 'GD поддерживает';
    else
      echo 'GD не поддерживает';
    
    ?>